# Image Processing Toolbox: how to register a callback for a ROI

Tags: matlab

I would like to register a callback when a ROI, returned by `drawpolygon` is clicked. The docs (https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/images.roi.polygon-class.html) say that there is an event `ROIClicked` for a ROI. However, I do not find a way to register a callback for this event.

```
f = figure(); 
imagesc(rand(64,64));
roi = drawpolygon();
```

Now, trying

```
roi.ROIClicked = @(~,~)disp('clicked');
```

fails with

```
Unrecognized property 'ROIClicked' for class 'images.roi.Polygon'.
```

and also

```
addlistener(roi, 'ROIClicked', 'PostSet', @(~,~)disp('clicked'));
```

fails with

```
Error using images.roi.Polygon/addlistener
The name 'ROIClicked' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'images.roi.Polygon'.
```

I might have missed something in the docs, but I'd like to know how to register a callback that is executed when a ROI i clicked?

Comment: Here is an example usage: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/use-wait-function-after-drawing-roi-example.html